# Simple MySQL error _SYM

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

Really simple question from a newbie (who has done a lot of googling to try to work it out!)

The below MySQL code is giving a Syntax error saying "check" is `UNEXPECTED_SYM`

```
ALTER TABLE check change AccountRef_ListID AccountListID VARCHAR(50)
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use the word `check` in MySQL as it is reserved words. Change your table name to new proper one.
Look into reserved words [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html), but it is just for MySQL 5.5.

Comment: Ah, I suspected that. Can do!

Comment: Yes you must change your table name to another one.